# What is the difference between nullable & _Nullable

Tags: objective-c, xcode

**nullable**

I find this syntax rather confusing:

```m
- (void)doSomething:(nullable void (^)(NSArray * _Nullable transactions))successBlock
            failure:(nullable void (^)(NSError * _Nullable error))failureBlock;
```

...not only because of the duality between `nullable` and `_Nullable`, but also because, while having the same intent, they are not interchangeable.

As found in [Nullability and Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=25):

- use `nullable` like you would use assertions
- `__nullable` is the old name of `nullable` between Xcode 6.3 and 7.0
- use `_Nullable` where you can use `const`

This makes little sense in the example above, since I have yet to see `void` defined as `const void`. Is there and even better version of nullable that could be used interchangeably?

---

**_Nonnull**, **_Null_unspecified**

Same puzzle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`nullable` is Objective C language syntax.  `_Nullable` is C language extension, which is inherited by Objective C.

Functions and blocks are part of the C language, so you must use `_Nullable` in those declarations.  Objective C method and property declarations can use either Objective C's `nullable` or C's `_Nullable`.

---

By the way, C function pointer and block syntax is confusing at the best of times.  It's often a good idea to use typedefs to simplify complex situations.

```
typedef void (^SuccessBlock)(NSArray* _Nullable transactions);

- (void)doSomething:(nullable SuccessBlock)successHandler;
```

Comment: Sorry, this was a duplicate. I had searched and not found it.